# UWP/WinRT: How to use VisualState Triggers to change the styling of all controls of a certain type?

Tags: responsive-design, windows-runtime, uwp

In my UWP app, I have a series of `AppBarButtons` separated by `AppBarSeparators`. When the window size drops below a certain amount, I want to hide the `AppBarSeparators` to save space.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
<VisualState.Setters>
   <Setter Target="AppBarSeparator" Value="Collapsed"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

I understand it's not possible to give each of the `AppBarSeparators` labels so I can target them directly, because they are dynamically generated as part of a binding.

So how can I hide all AppBarSeparators when my window shrinks below a certain size?

Edit: Here is a stripped down version of my XAML to show how the AppBarSeparators are being generated:

```
<Pivot x:Name="docPivot"
       ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="0">
                    <AppBarButton/>
                    <AppBarSeparator/>
                    <AppBarButton/>
                    <AppBarButton/>
                    <AppBarSeparator/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="1">
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>

</Pivot>
```

Comment: "they are dynamically generated as part of a binding." Your `AppBarSeparators` are generated in the code behind, you didn't design them in the xaml?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT No, they're in the xaml, generated as part of a binding from a Pivot

Comment: Could you please show some xaml code?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Updated my post with XAML

Comment: OK, I can understand now, your `AppBarSeparators` are in `DataTemplate`, they are not exposed, the controls inside actually become the visual structure of your data objects, so using visualstate trigger here can not solve the problem, but you can use databinding with converter here. Is that OK if I write a demo here as the answer?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Sure, I would love any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed in the comment, your `AppBarSeparators` are generated in the `Pivot`'s `DataTemplate`, when controls are placed inside the `DateTemplate`, they becomes the visual structure of your data objects, but `VisualState` targets the controls, so can it not work here.

You can use DataBinding with [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to do this, and if the size of the window is changeable during the run-time, you may also need complete your data source class with [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

For example here:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolVisibleConverter x:Key="cvt" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot x:Name="docPivot" ItemsSource="{x:Bind pivotlist}" SizeChanged="docPivot_SizeChanged">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept" />
                        <AppBarSeparator Visibility="{Binding WindowWidth, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" />
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel" />
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add" />
                        <AppBarSeparator Visibility="{Binding WindowWidth, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Code behind, I used [FrameworkElement.SizeChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.SizeChanged);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) to get the window's width during the run-time, if you just want to make the layout fit for mobile or PC at the first time the layout loading is, then this event is not needed, neither is the `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MyPivotItem> pivotlist = new ObservableCollection<MyPivotItem>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    pivotlist.Clear();
    pivotlist.Add(new MyPivotItem { });
    pivotlist.Add(new MyPivotItem { });
    pivotlist.Add(new MyPivotItem { });
    pivotlist.Add(new MyPivotItem { });
}

private void docPivot_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in docPivot.Items)
    {
        var pivotitem = item as MyPivotItem;
        pivotitem.WindowWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }
}
```

The `MyPivotItem` class is like this:

```cs
public class MyPivotItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyPivotItem()
    {
        _windowwidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }

    private double _windowwidth;

    public double WindowWidth
    {
        get { return _windowwidth; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _windowwidth)
            {
                _windowwidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the `BoolVisibleConverter` is quite simple here:

```cs
public class BoolVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        double? width = (double?)value;
        if (width <= 700)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just found that if you don't want it be changed in run-time, it may be easier using `ItemTemplateSelector` to do this.

Comment: So you are involving view-models with a view related thing? I think "Window Size" is a pure view issue and should not be exposed to view-models. I usually don't have a single reference to Windows.UI in view-model layer.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz, since OP didn't mention that he used MVVM pattern, I'm here didn't involving MVVM, but you are right, if this is a MVVM project, windows size should not be exposed to view models.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a dependency property in your page:

```
sealed partial class Page1: Page {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty SeparatorVisibilityProperty = 
                            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SeparatorVisibility",
                                           typeof(Visibility),
                                           typeof(Page1),
                                           new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible)
                            );
    public bool SeparatorVisibility {
         get {
            return (Visibility)this.GetValue(SeparatorVisibilityProperty);
         }
         set {
             this.SetValue(SeparatorVisibilityProperty , value);
         }
    }
    ..
    ..
```

Then bind Visibility property of the AppBarSeparators to this property:

```
<Page ...
      ...
      x:Name="page">
    .. 
    ..
    <AppBarSeparator Visibility="{Binding ElementName=page, Path=SeparatorVisibility}"/>
    ..
```

Then change the SeparatorVisibility property of the page in the visual state:

```
<VisualState.Setters>
   <Setter Target="page.SeparatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

The visual state changes the page property, it will change visibility of AppBarSeparators since their Visibility property are bound to the SeparatorVisibility property of the page. Not sure if it is the best solution, it's just what comes to my mind now.

Comment: What did you mean in the first sentence? Are you saying it is possible to give them names and reach them all via that mechanism?

Comment: @WilliamJones I wasn't sure whether it is possible or not, which is not. I remove that sentence.